# @reduxjs/toolkit Intellisense not appearing in VS Code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense

Using vscode, intellisense does not detect @reduxjs/toolkit. The code is working but the intellisense is not. I already have [ES7+ React/Redux/React-Native snippets extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dsznajder.es7-react-js-snippets)

Here are 2 examples:

1. No import autocomplete.
   Additionally, when I finish typing the whole thing `import { createSlice, configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";`, ctrl + left click to the library does not take me to its corresponding node_modules directory. Nothing happens.

[image]

2. The variable returned by createSlice() does not trigger autocomplete. The expected result is `increment, decrement, increase, toggleCounter` ie `counterslice.actions.increment`

[image]

Any ideas on the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my jsconfig.js to this and the autocomplete/intellisense from all dependencies finally worked.

```
{
  "typeAcquisition": {
    "include": [
      "jest"
    ]
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es6",
    "jsx": "react",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
  },
   "include": [
     "src/**/*"
   ],
}
```

It is probably the line `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true`